# project ':wakelock' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

Tags: android, flutter

This is the entire error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':wakelock' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 698ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1,181ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

This error happens when I try to do either of these commands: Flutter build apk OR Flutter build appbundle.

I have tried to change the kotlin verions in the android build.gradle files, but I still have this issue. When I tried to change the gradle version, I get another issue which is:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.0/gradle-7.5.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.0/gradle-7.5.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.0/gradle-7.5.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.0/gradle-7.5.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Any Help?

Comment: Can you show me the codes contains in the following 3 files:
**1. android -> build.gradle**
**2. android -> app -> build.gradle**
**3. android -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties**

Comment: Have the same problem but not able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly this issue yesterday after importing flutter project to Android Studio after creating a new project with wakelock dependency by "flutter create" command.

Then, I made flutter clean, left only necessary files (created by me) in the project folder and made "flutter create ." inside the project directory.

Then I opened the project from Android Studio by File/Open and not by New/Import as I did before, and the problem is fixed now.

I remember that Project/Import asked many stupid questions including Kotlin config, so may be this is the cause of the problem.